# UI-Router: param values not valid for state

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

the [github repo](https://github.com/eyalcohen4/ui-router-example) for this question. I'm absolutely hopeless. I create a angular 1.5.8 app, that show nodes on screen. there are 2 types of nodes - Folders and Pictures.

When click on picture node, it should pass the `params` using *ui-router*, and Im doing as the *ui-router* docs says.

Interpolation of `{{picture.url}}` and everything else work just fine and provide the right path to files.

what is strange is when I'm doing it manually, by go to: `/picture/url`
it is pass the path to file. The error i get is:

> Param values not valid for state 'picture'

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouteProvide) {
           $stateProvider
            .state('picture', {
                url:'/picture/:url',
                template:'<h1> Picture </h1> <br /> <img  class="mainImg" src={{ctrl.pic}} />`',
                controller:function($stateParams) {
                    console.log($stateParams);
                    this.pic = `../img/${$stateParams.url}`
                },
                controllerAs: 'ctrl'
        });
     });
```

And :

```
<ul>
  <li class='picture' ng-repeat='picture in home.pictures track by $index'>
    <a ui-sref='picture({ url: {{picture.url}} })'> {{picture.type}} </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any help will be great. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using

```
ui-sref='picture({ url: picture.url })'
```

Instead of

```
ui-sref='picture({ url: {{picture.url}} })'
```

See http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref for more information and examples.

Comment: Glad to have helped.  Be sure to mark as answer if it worked for you.